# How To Do CRUD Operations in WEBAPI in asp.net using AJAX

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing, wcf-web-api

I would like to perform CRUD Operations on WEB API in asp.net using AJAX JQuery.I am very new to web api

Comment: Your question was too broad, you have to do some research and get started. If you have any technical coding problems, please post them here.

Comment: try to learn from this [post](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2b481f/using-crud-operation-in-Asp-Net-web-api/) but he is using knockoutjs instead of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

The Following Code can be used to hit a web api with a GET Request

```
    var url1 = 'http://api.com/customer/1234';

    $.ajax({
        url: url1,
        type: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'customHeader': 'Value',
            'customHeader2': 'Value2'
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert('Success');
        }
    });
```